# can pfsense perform ipv6 nat (for outbound service redirection)

Tags: nat, ipv6, pfsense

I have to keep prefacing my question with "I am not trying to reimplement ipv4 nat inbound for outdated security I don't understand correctly".

Hi! I am wondering if it is possible to implement an ipv6 nat under pfsense.  My goal is to perform the nat on the **LAN** interface so that I can redirect any outbound v6 port 53 into a local v6 dns server.  My ISP (comcast) does not allow me to configure my own v6 server on their router, and they do not allow me to do prefix delegation requests.  I just want to hijack the requests going to their auto-learned DNS servers into a server that has beter than 98.5% uptime. *Please note: I am not interested in making changes to my ISP, etc.*

I literally want a rule that says "packets coming in on this interface with a source address of my lan clients and destination of any, destination port 53, protocols udp and tcp, go to this local ipv6 global address on port 53."

It works just fine on ipv4.  I do not suspect this capability exists in pfsense, but would like someone a bit of an expert to give advice.  Thanks.

Comment: Linux ip6tables provides a TPROXY target which can do this, but the catch is that the application receiving the packets must be TPROXY-aware, and as far as I know no DNS servers are.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

https://forum.pfsense.org/index.php?topic=89014.0

An expert finally responded - the answer is no, pfSense provides no IPv6 NAT capabilities.